# Android: Error in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to learn game programming in `Android`. I have set GPU emulation in the AVD to "yes" and the AndEngine library version to be 4.1

I have also set the version of project be 4.1 but still the following error occurs please help me.

I am using the sample code for tower of hanoi.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:183)
D/gralloc_goldfish(786): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
E/AndroidRuntime(786): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 101
E/AndroidRuntime(786): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig found!
E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:183)
E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:157)
E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1009)
E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1362)
E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method `org.andengine.AndEngine.IsDeviceSupported()`, to check if your device is supported.
If you have a ancient graphics card, you can not enable GPU emulation forever.
See [this thread](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/getting-started-with-andengine-t4858.html)'s 1st post, section 'TIPS AND TRICKS' for detail.