# my andengine gles2 game keeps on crashing

Tags: java, android, andengine

My andengine game just keep on crashing.May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?
i got it from here its a source
https://github.com/sm4/FlyingDandelion

---

```
03-24 05:14:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1207): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 88
03-24 05:14:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1207): Process: is.kul.flappydandelion, PID: 1207
03-24 05:14:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1207): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig found!
03-24 05:14:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:229)
03-24 05:14:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:203)
03-24 05:14:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
03-24 05:14:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
03-24 05:14:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: Are u running it on an emulator? Did it run on real device?

Comment: see this question for some ideas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679007/no-eglconfig-found